# changing properties of item in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I’m developing a application that will borrow a car to the user, user can choose from the fleet available. Unfortunately when registration number is typed in and name of the borrower is given, program assigns that person to the first entry in arrayList that has been added. I’m not sure how to get program to assign borrower to the item with given registration number. Can anyone point out the mistake I’m making?

Method that sets borrower:

```
    public void askBorrower(){
    boolean loop = false;
    while(!loop){
        String bName = Console.askString("Borrower's Name: ");
        while(bName.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Borrower's name cannot be empty!");
            bName = Console.askString("Borrower's Name: ");
        }
        while(!bName.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
            System.out.println("Letters only allowed!");
            bName = Console.askString("Borrower's Name: ");
        }
        setBorrower(bName);
        loop = true;
        boolean newAvailability = false;
        setAvailability(newAvailability);
        System.out.println("You have successfully borrowed a car.");
    }
}
```

In main class switch triggering borrowing process:

```
 case 4:
               System.out.println("Borrowing a car:");
               System.out.println("");
               sCar = new StaffCar(); 
               sCar.askRegNo();
               sCar = (StaffCar)fleet2.find(sCar.getRegNo());
               if(sCar == null){
                   System.out.println("Car not in the fleet, please try again");
               }
               else if(sCar.availability == false){
                   System.out.println("Car is out on loan currently");
               }
               else{
                  sCar.askBorrower();
               }
               break;
```

and find method:

```
    public StaffCar find(String regNo){ 
    int index = regNo.indexOf(regNo);
    if(index == -1){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return fleet2.get(index);

    }
}
```

I would very much appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Comment: `regNo.indexOf(regNo)` will always return 0. You are looking for a string inside itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int index = regNo.indexOf(regNo);
```

Is searching for the registration number in the registration number String, which will always return 0.

You need to search for the registration number in the List. Since `fleet2` is a `List<StaffCar>`, you can't use `indexOf(regNo)` to locate a car by its registration number. You have to iterate over the `List` by yourself.

```
for (StaffCar car : fleet2) {
    if (car.getRegNo().equals(regNo))
        return car;
}
return null;
```

Comment: Beat me to it =/ This is indeed your problem.

Comment: Technically if `StaffCar` only checks for equality based on `regNo`, `fleet2.indexOf(new StaffCar(regNo));` would also work.

Comment: @River No it wouldn't, unless `StaffCar`'s equals may return true when comparing a StaffCar instance to a String instance, which would be strange.

Comment: Where do you get a `String` instance from? `fleet2` is a list of `StaffCar` and I'm passing `indexOf` a `StaffCar` as well.

Comment: @River `regNo` is a String. Oh, I didn't notice you were creating a new instance of `StaffCar` and passing it the `regNo`. Well, that's assuming such a constructor exists, and assuming `equals` behaves as you think it does.

Comment: Well the constructor used hardly matters, as long as one that sets `regNo` exists, and has the right number/type of variables passed to it. But yes, assuming my assumption (which is why it's an assumption...) was correct.

Comment: Although, now that I look back, if this were the case, he could just call `find` on his original car instead of it's `regNo`. (He specifically does `find(sCar.getRegNo())` which would be silly, as `find(sCar)` is much easier, if my case were true.)

Comment: @River Well, even if your assumptions are correct, creating a new instance just to be able to use ArrayList's indexOf method is wasteful. indexOf iterates over the elements of the List just like my for loop does, so since using indexOf requires the extra work of creating that instance, it's not worth it.

Comment: See my above comment. An extra instance would actually not be needed.

Comment: @River Hmm, I didn't notice how `find` was actually used. You got a point there.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = regNo.indexOf(regNo);
```

this line will always return 0 because you're querying for the index position of a string in the string itself position of 'dog' in 'dog' is always 0.

Assuming you fleet2 is a List, the `indexOf` method will only give you the position of the element you're passing as parameter. I.e. `indexOf(aStaffCar)` will give you the position of the car while `indexOf(aString)` will always gives you -1. 
I'd sugest you use a `Map<String,StaffCar>` with the `String regNo` being the key.

```
Map<String,StaffCar> fleet2 = ...,

public StaffCar find(String regNo){ 
  //will return null if no entry with key regNo found
  return fleet2.get(regNo);
}
```

Comment: Love the suggestion for O(1) lookup